# .htaccess email regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^email_veri/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$/ email_veri.php?email=$1&usr=$2
RewriteRule ^email_veri/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ email_veri.php?email=$1&usr=$2
```

As you can see I cannot accept email's, since my regex isn't allowing it. But when I do `([a-zA-Z0-9]@+)` it doesn't wok.

Comment: let everything through to the file and use php's built in `filter_var` to decide whether or not the email is valid, my 2 cents.. http://php.net/filter_var

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]@+` means one alphanumeric character then any number of `@` character (>0). So simply it shouldn't match an email address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Please give examples of the URLs you are requesting, that you want rewritten.